# Can I pass a value out of a javascript function?

Tags: javascript

Can I pass a value out of a javascript function and back to the calling function, e.g.

```
function updateURL(url, name, param) {
  url = url + "&" + name + "=" + param;
}
```

I want to update url and return the new value.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're asking for is called "[pass-by-reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference)".  Javascript uses "[pass-by-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value)" for the native types (int, string, etc)---other types are pass-by-reference.  For your specific case, I can think of two ways to get what you want.  The first is to require callers to pass in an array with a single element and modify that element:

```
function updateURL(url, name, param) {
    url[0] = url[0] + "&" + name + "=" + param;
}
url = ['http://www.google.com/?'];
updateURL(url, 'foo', 'bar');
alert(url[0]);
```

The second method would be to use an attribute on an object:

```
function updateURL(url, name, param) {
    url.url = url.url + "&" + name + "=" + param;
}
url = new Object();
url.url = 'http://www.google.com/?';
updateURL(url, 'foo', 'bar');
alert(url.url);
```

Comment: Ah, I see, not worth the effort really in my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
function parentFunction() {
    var url = 'http://www.example.com?qs=1';
    var name = 'foo';
    var param= 'bar';
    var newUrl = updateURL(url, name, param);
}

function updateURL(url, name, param) {
  url = url + "&" + name + "=" + param;
  return url;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't this just set the return value of the function?

I would like to call it like:

function parentFunction() {
    var url = '';
    var name = '';
    var param= '';
    updateURL(url, name, param);
}

Comment: I see, but what I am trying to find out is does Javascript have "out" parameters or are all parameters "in" parameters?

Comment: I saw you updated  your comment, can you expand on what you want. The updateURL function will return a string of the concatenated URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myUrl = updateUrl('url', 'name', 'param');

function updateURL(url, name, param) {
  url = url + "&" + name + "=" + param;
  return url;
}
```